# How to fix jQuery/PHP form submission?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am updating a client site and the simple contact form that used to work is now broken. It appears that the HTML form sends and receives data from the jQuery file as I get the error messages returned, though it is not passing the data through to the PHP file for sending an email. If I send the data direct from the HTML form to the PHP file, then an email is sent. The error is probably at the end of the jQuery, though my search for how to fix has not revealed an answer. Any ideas on how to make this work?

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="rsForm" action="#" onsubmit="return goContact(this);" name="rsForm">
<input id="formNam" type="hidden" name="formNam" value="3" />
<div class="CU_row">
<div class="CU_form_title"><label for="firstName">First Name:</label></div>
<div class="CU_form_entry"><input id="firstName" maxlength="120" size="39" name="first" type="text" /> <span class="redT">*</span></div>
</div>
<div class="CU_row">
<div class="CU_form_title"><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label></div>
<div class="CU_form_entry"><input id="lastName" maxlength="120" size="39" name="last" type="text" /> <span class="redT">*</span></div>
</div>
<div class="CU_row">
<div class="CU_form_title"><label for="emailAddress">Email:</label></div>
<div class="CU_form_entry"><input id="emailAddress" maxlength="120" size="39" name="email" type="text" /> <span class="redT">*</span></div>
</div>
<div class="CU_row">
<div class="CU_form_title"><label for="subjectLine">Subject:</label></div>
<div class="CU_form_entry"><input id="subjectLine" maxlength="120" size="39" name="subject" type="text" /> <span class="redT">*</span></div>
</div>
<div class="CU_row">
<div class="CU_form_title"><label for="messageCopy">Message:</label></div>
<div class="CU_form_entry"><textarea id="messageCopy" rows="6" cols="30" name="message"></textarea> <span class="redT">*</span></div>
</div>
<div id="CU_reset"><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></div>
<div id="CU_submit"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></div>
```

**jQuery File**

```
// JavaScript Document

function goContact(theForm){
//Validate the forms and create the array to send.
var frmName = theForm.formNam.value;


//Validate Common elements.
if(theForm.firstName.value.length < 1){
    alert("You must supply a First Name");
    theForm.firstName.focus();
    return false;
}
if(theForm.lastName.value.length < 1){
    alert("You must supply a Last Name");
    theForm.lastName.focus();
    return false;
}
if(theForm.email.value.length < 1){
    alert("You must supply an Email");
    theForm.email.focus();
    return false;
}
if(theForm.subjectLine.value.length < 1){
    alert("You must supply a Subject");
    theForm.subjectLine.focus();
    return false;
}
if(theForm.messageCopy.value.length < 1){
    alert("You must supply a Message");
    theForm.messageCopy.focus();
    return false;
}

sendAjaxReq($(theForm).serialize(true));

return false;   
}

function showResult(messageText){
//Show the pop up with the confirmation.
$('msgWindow').innerHTML = messageText;
$('rsForm').reset();
$('frmInter').hide();
}

function sendAjaxReq(formEms){
//Send he ajax request
 var rSp = new Ajax.Request("includes/sendContact.php", {
        method: 'get',
        parameters: formEms,
        onComplete: receiveRespon});

}

function receiveRespon(oReq, JSONRsp){
//Receive the response from the ajax request.\
var result = JSONRsp;

if(result){
    showResult(result);
}
}
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php 


if(isset($_GET['Submit'])){
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: no-reply@sitename.com' . "\r\n";
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$to = "info@sitename.com";
$subject = "Inquiry from " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$message = "A client has sent a contact us email\n\n";

foreach($_GET AS $field => $value) {
    $message .= "field = $field, value = $value \n\n";
}

$mailSent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    $arr = "Your message has been received.";
    header('X-JSON: ('.json_encode($arr).')'); 

}

?>
```

Comment: What did you change? Did you update your version of jQuery? Stuff doesn't just stop working for no reason.

Comment: The $(theForm).serialize(true) and new Ajax.Request() looks like prototype not jQuery

Comment: @relentless the code worked in an old version of the site and now after many updates, I noticed it does not.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I will research it.

Comment: Is the site under version control? Sounds like a job for `git bisect`

Comment: Mike, this site is not under version control. I recently started using it on projects. It took some time to learn and setup, though it's been worth it.